# spring controller does not work when I extend it

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, controller

i try make a generic controller with some methods, so i don´t need re-writer common codes, but don´t work, why???

```
@Controller("/home/teste")
public class CtrlTeste extends ControladorGenericoSpring<Assistenciado>
{
public String path;

    public CtrlTeste()
    {
       super(Assistenciado.class);
       path = "/home/teste";
       setPacoteServico("servico.assistenciado");
       setPrefixo("Serv");
       setNomeEntidade("Assistênciado");        

    }

   @RequestMapping
   public String teste(@RequestParam(value = "id", required= true)Long id, Model model)
   {
      Assistenciado ass = getServico().buscarPorId(id);
      model.addAttribute("assistenciado", ass);
      return "/home";
   }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're currently specifying the name of the bean. Try with:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home/teste")
public class CtrlTeste extends ControladorGenericoSpring<Assistenciado> {
    ...
}
```

Comment: it worked, thanks dude, this rookie mistake ¬ ¬, I was so excited to leave everything generic I forgot one thing I do all the time and did not even realize, thks

Comment: @DiegoAndrade: You're welcome, but here users usually thank others voting or accepting their answers :)